# Embedding website in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a question regarding google calendar. i am new to it so not sure if i  am asking correct question.

I want to integrate google calendar appointments with one of my application. what i want to do is

- I should be able to integrate a web application with in google
  calendar. Basically there should be some sort of button on appointment window which will take user to a webpage
- Whenever user creates an appointment user should be able to set some
  custom props on appointment
- Webapp should be able to set location with in google calendar
- As soon as user saves appointment all of the relevant information
  should be saved in database.

i want to know if its possible at all. actually i  want to achieve something similar like outlook addins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try reading the [Get Started with the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview):

> The Calendar API lets you display, create and modify calendar events as well as work with many other calendar-related objects, such as calendars or access controls. This document describes how to use RESTful calls and client libraries for various programming languages (Java, PHP, .NET, JavaScript, NodeJs, Ruby, Python, Go, Android, iOS).

All your question is possible and will all depend on your implementation. You might want to check this tutorial - [Google Calendar API with JavaScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986631/Google-Calendar-API-with-JavaScript), this will help you develop a web application to create or display Calendar data.

Hope this helps.